# Verificar se array contem valor selecionado numa consulta mySQL com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Será que poderiam me ajudar? 
Preciso verificar se array contem um valor específico numa consulta mySQL. 
Numa função eu obtenho o valor dia da semana:

```
$wekc = 4
```

Na table tb_turg, eu possuo a coluna weekg que guarda os valores assim:

```
idturg weekg
1      1,3,5
2      1,2,4
3      0,4
4      3,6
5      4,6
6      1,2
7      1,4,6
8      0,1,2,3,
9      2,4
10     3,5
```

Depois eu criei o array assim:

```
$sqlturg = "SELECT weekg,abng,classg FROM tb_turg WHERE abng != '$nwdatefer' AND classg = '1' ORDER BY idturg ASC";
$querya = $conn->query($sqlturg);
while($rowtg = $querya->fetch_assoc()) {
$weekg = $rowtg["weekg"];

@$nwekga .= $weekg." - ";
}
```

Depois separei este array:

```
$nwekg = rtrim($nwekga, ' - ');
$aw = explode(' - ', $nwekg);
foreach($aw as $bw) {
$cw = $bw;

$sqlga = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT idturg,weekg FROM tb_turg WHERE weekg = '$cw' AND classg = '1' ORDER BY idmodg ASC");
$rowtga = $sqlga->fetch_assoc();
$idturg = $rowtga["idturg"];
$ag = $rowtga["weekg"];

$fw = explode(',', $ag);
foreach($fw as $gw) {
$hw = $gw;
}

if (in_array($wekc, $fw)) { 

$sqlgb = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT idturg,codturg FROM tb_turg WHERE idturg = '$idturg' AND classg = '1'");
$rowtgb = $sqlgb->fetch_assoc();
$idturg = $rowtgb["idturg"];
$codturg = $rowtgb["codturg"];

echo $idturg . "<br>";
} else {
echo "";
}

}
```

Mas não está dando certo, pois ele está repetindo resultados da consulta $sqlgb 
**CONCLUSÃO: Ele teria que listar os idturg somente das linhas que possuem o dia 4 (Quinta-feira), sem repetir.**

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVIDO: 
Era só fazer assim: FIND_IN_SET($wekc,weekg)

```
$sqlturg = "SELECT idturg FROM tb_turg WHERE FIND_IN_SET($wekc,weekg) AND classg = '1'"
```

E só necessitaria de uma só consulta... aff 
Desculpem, mas é que estou aprendendo ainda.